# node geoip installation fail

Tags: node.js, npm, geoip

When install geoip package: npm install geoip, I got the following error. I also tried install nodejs-legacy package on ubuntu but still has the same error. Any one came across same issue before ?

```
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/qiong/dev/startup/webrtc/sample/chatboxx/node_modules/geoip
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! geoip@0.5.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the geoip@0.5.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the geoip package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls geoip
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "geoip"
npm ERR! cwd /home/qiong/dev/startup/webrtc/sample/chatboxx
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/qiong/dev/startup/webrtc/sample/chatboxx/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: The first line says that running 'node -e "require('nan')' failed.  When I try that on my ubuntu I get: Error: Cannot find module 'nan'  .. could you simply be missing the 'nan' dependency, whatever that is?

Answer (score 0):

I used this package - https://www.npmjs.org/package/geoip-native, it is quite old, but it works ok. Also you can download actual CSV file of zones from maxmind for it. 
usually if it sayes that node-gyp failed, there can be some c++ bindings not installed.
try `su -c 'apt-get install build-essential'` to install dependencies needed for compiling binary modueles